# Making multiple new indesign documents from data in excel spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, excel, adobe-indesign

Preface: I'm a graphic design and know very little about coding. For a project I'm working on I have to produce over 200 InDesign documents, with different names, widths and heights.

This is what I need the script to do:

- Make a new document in InDesign
- Take the document name,  page height, page width data from excel spreadsheet
- Make new frame (w: width of the page h: height of the page+ 40mm)
- Center the frame to the page
- Place a specific .tif inside the frame
- Align bottom of the image to the centre bottom of the frame
- Save the file in the selected folder
- Select data from next row down in the excel file
- Repeat

I'm a complete beginner, but I'd like to write this program and learn as I go.

Any advice or direction as to how I could write this would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a link to Adobe's reference on scripting InDesign with javascript: [https://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS4.pdf](https://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS4.pdf)

Comment: Do you actually have to save 200 *.indd-Documents* or do you just need 200 PDFs in the end?

Answer (score -1):

Adobe indesign allows scripting in Javascript, AppleScript, VBScript. Good for task like automating similar .indd documents.
Here's the link that may be helpful:
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingTutorial.pdf